# Setting $_SESSION doesn't work on localhost using XAMPP

Tags: php, session, localhost

I set my session like so in my PHP code : `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;` and this seems to work fine whilst uploaded to my server and carries across different pages, however when I am testing the website on my local machine the session seems to become immediately unset after leaving the script where it is set.

I am testing on my local machine using XAMPP and exactly the same code.

I am not sure why this problem is occurring and would greatly appreciate any helpful answer.

#### Example that is not working:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=../home.php">';
```

#### EDIT 1:

Here is my entire function in which I *log in* (it's part of the class):

```
public function loggingIn(){
    session_start();

    $db = new Database('localhost','root','','userdata');
    $userFunctions = new Users($db);

    $username = $_POST['usernameInput'];
    $password = $_POST['passwordInput'];

    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
        $this->errors['u&p'] = 'Please Enter Your Username AND Password';
        $this->printE();
    } elseif($userFunctions->user_exists($username)===false){
        $this->errors['nm'] = 'That Username/Password Combination Is Not Valid';
        $this->printE();
    } else {
            $login = $userFunctions->login($username, $password);

    if($login === false){
            $this->errors['nm'] = 'That Username/Password Combination Is Not Valid';
            echo 'Login Failed!';
        } else  {
           if(!$userFunctions->economyTableExistsForUser($login)){
               $userFunctions->createEconomyTableForUser($login);   
           }
           if(!$userFunctions->schoolTableExistsForUser($login)) {
               $userFunctions->createSchoolTableForUser($login);    
           }

               $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;

               echo $_SESSION['user_id'];  // working fine

               header('Location: ../home.php');
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Let's guess that your home machine is not having:

`session.autostart = On`

in your [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.php), while your other machine obviously is.

Make sure that you have set in your PHP code:

`session_start();`

[PHP: session_start - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)

If you don't, then your session is not started, unless my first conjecture is true.

Besides, you must check for you *PHP* version on your localhost and settings in *php.ini*. Make sure that the directory where you store you session files is writeable and session files do really exist.

#### EDIT 1:

You better use PHP solution for redirection:

```
header("Location: /");
exit();
```

#### EDIT 2:

PHP has functions that modify HTTP headers. Some of them:

- [header](http://php.net/header)
- [session_start](http://php.net/session_start)
- [setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie)

#### EDIT 3:

Line-breaks and spaces could be a problem but there are also invisible character sequences which can cause `Warning: Cannot modify header information`, like the [UTF-8 BOM (Byte-Order-Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
Try re-saving your file making sure that it's saved just as `UTF-8 (no BOM)`.

#### EDIT 4:

To properly debug your code make sure that PHP displays all warning and notices. Run it before session start:

```
ini_set('display_errors', -1);
```

#### EDIT 5:

You must also check `session.gc_maxlifetime` setting:

> **session.gc_maxlifetime**
>   *session.gc_maxlifetime* specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and cleaned up. Garbage collection occurs during session start.

#### EDIT 6:

To view white-spaces in Sublime Text, edit the settings:

```
// Set to "none" to turn off drawing white space, "selection" to draw only the
// white space within the selection, and "all" to draw all white space
"draw_white_space": "selection",
```

You can set it in Preferences->Settings Default. If you edit your user settings Preferences->Settings - User and add the line as per below:

```
{
    "font_size": 10,
    "draw_white_space": "all"
}
```

Also make sure it shows all other special characters to properly debug your code!

#### EDIT 7:

Finally try adding `session_write_close();` right before redirecting.

#### EDIT 8:

Set in your PHP file, before `session_start();`, `session.save_path = "/home/username/tmp";` directive. 
Create `tmp` dir outside of *public_html*.  Make sure that `tmp` dir has *chmod  770* and created with the same user/group privileges . Run `ls -lsa` in your home dir to check if the new directory has the same *user/group* as other directories, like *public_html* for instance. If not, make sure changing permissions as root on `tmp` by running `chown username:groupname /home/username/tmp`.

Comment: I do in fact do this, sorry I didn't mention it. I have now included it in the original post.

Comment: Ah now doing that produces and error on my server saying something along the lines of "PHP Headers already sent"... this is why I used this form of redirection.

Comment: Okay so I have tried header to redirect and the session variable still doesn't seem to carry across the page. Also this is the only real bit I can see helping. I try echoing it in the script right after I set it and it works so it is definitely getting set.

Comment: It echos the user_id retrieved from a database, this works on my server and also works on localhost, as I mentioned the variable is definitely getting set

Comment: I use Sublime text editor, also the session.gc_maxlifetime is set at 24 minutes

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the entire method in which I log in, thanks for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes it is part of a class, just to throw it out there is it possible that the header is redirecting before the session variable has a chance to set, this could be why it works on the same page?

Comment: No I added session_write_close(); just before I redirect and it does not seem to do anything

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: Okay thanks for all of your help , I will try that , and talk to you tomorrow too!

Comment: Just as a note, I tried it with a simple PHP file, just setting the variable, redirecting then trying to print it out however it still does not carry over.

Comment: Then you must check for you PHP version on your localhost and settings in php.ini. Make sure that the directory where you store you session files is writeable and session files do really exist. 

You shouldn't add what you have forgotten at the very beginning in your answer, meaning *session_start();* as it makes unclear my answer. Change it to edits please, so it would be clear.

Comment: Okay I included the edit thing and also I am running PHP 5.3.8 on both my local machine and my server.

Comment: Do what I written in *EDIT 8* please! It's definitely there! There is no other reason for that! And please let's remove so many comments! They ask kindly to move it to chat!

Comment: Josh, was there any of luck?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Yes, totally agree and now I'm aware about this for sure. Fixed it. I read your answer, nice. Thanks.

Comment: session.autostart = On did the trick on xampp in mac environment.

Answer (score 4):

A quick update on this.  I found this response very useful, however, please note that in my installation of XAMPP, the php.ini entry for session.autostart=On, is slightly different.  I found the following:

; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start=0

I changed this to:

; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start=1

Answer (score 2):

Make sure session cookies are enabled in `php.ini` (`xamp\php\php.ini`).

```
session.use_cookies=1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini check:

1. [`variables_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) contains the letter `S`
2. Check that [`session.save_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) exists and is writeable by the user under which PHP is running.

Comment: Yes it contains the letter "S" and the session.save_path is accessible and contains the set session files

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP embedded within .htm/.html documents, you need to ensure that Apache can process them appropriately. This is done by editing the httpd.conf and adding the line

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

to the section `<IfModule mime_module>`

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting with this problem but solve...

In your `/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` try to change this line:

```
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
```

For this:

```
session.save_path = "/opt/lampp/var/session"
```

Note: Maybe you need to create the folder "session" in `/opt/lampp/var`

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `php.ini`
2. change session.auto_start with `"1"`
3. `"Stop"` Apache if running
4. "`Save"` `php.ini`
5. `"Start"` Apache

Answer (score 0):

```
Session Issue Fixed in Xampp 7.1.6 with following Changes in php.ini
Line #1403 set: 
session.auto_start = 1
```

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer. Answering without explanations is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems live site working Xampp not.

The trick in my case was to **disable** the two lines below.

```
header('Set-Cookie: same-site-cookie=huis; SameSite=Lax');
header('Set-Cookie: cross-site-cookie=stijl; SameSite=None; Secure');
```

So check anything that **modifies something regarding coockies** is my advise.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your "session.cookie_path" in php ini. By default it is "session.cookie_path=/"

Answer (score -1):

Enable session cookies in php.ini (C:\xamp\php\php.ini).

CHANGE

```
session.use_cookies=0
```

TO

```
session.use_cookies=1
```

AND remember to restart xampp