# Why I can't start session and echo my session id?

Tags: php, session

I am using Xampp version 7.0.1-0 . I am using the default port as usual. Everything works fine but while starting a session, the browser can't access the page, rather than it says "This site can't be reached". Here is the simple php code what's I am trying:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();

    echo session_id();
?>
```

I tried different browsers but the problem still remains. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: could you start your wamp server ?

Comment: I haven't tried the wamp server. Let me check if the problem still remains the same after using wamp.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. It worked on wamp. But do you know why it's creating problem in xampp? One of my friends is also having the same issue. I just want to know the reason if there's a solution.

Comment: may be this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644624/setting-session-doesnt-work-on-localhost-using-xampp

Comment: Thank you. You guys are so much helpful :)

Comment: Mine Pleasure. Enjoy coding :)